# Perl multi-threading code killed in the middle

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have a piece of Perl multithread code as follows. I have two questions:

1. the length of @correlatedPttns array is about 500. When executing, I used htop in linux to check how many processes are running, it seems only 3 processes are using. Isn't it supposed to create more threads?
2. the program crashed in the middle, when it finishes about 140 $pairs. Why did it happened? If I run the same piece of code on a small number of @correlatedPttns, then it worked fine.

Thanks!

code:

```
my @threads = ();
foreach my $pair (@correlatedPttns)
{    
   # slice the data out
    my @tmp = ();
    for (my $x = 0; $x<$cnt; $x++)
    {    
        push @tmp,[ @{ $data[$x] } [ 0, @$pair[0], @$pair[1] ] ]; 
    }    
   push (@threads, threads->create (\&thread_func, $pair, \@pttnIndexMap, \@tmp,$cnt, $intervalOutput));
}

foreach (@threads)
{
   $_->join(); # blocks until this thread exits
}
```

Comment: When the program crashes, is there any error message? What exactly does the error say?

Comment: Re "*I used htop in linux to check how many processes are running, it seems only 3 processes are using. Isn't it supposed to create more threads?*", uh, threads aren't processes.

Answer (score 0):

OK, stop for a moment - backtrack a bit, and rethink your understanding of threads.

In `perl` a thread is *not* a lightweight thing, like you seem to be assuming. It's a full copy of your program. If you spin up 500 threads, you're going to exhaust your system resources in a real hurry. Also - thread startup is not a lightweight process. It's actually a bad idea to do what you're doing. (Although doing it via `fork()` isn't as much of a problem, if you really wanted to go that way).

If I had to guess (and I do, because you haven't given us enough information) then I would guess your 'crash' was due to out of memory, and your process getting killed. `/var/log/messages` or similar should tell you.

I don't know why `htop` isn't doing what you think - try `ps -eft` and see if that does it?

However, I'd strongly urge a rewrite of your code - if you have a sequence of things to process that aren't coupled, then it would be MUCH more sensible to use `Thread::Queue` and a set of worker threads.

Rewrite `thread_func` like so:

```
my $workers = 10; 
my $work_q = Thread::Queue -> new(); 

sub thread_func { 
   while ( my $pair = $work_q -> dequeue ) { 
        ## all the messing around you do with each pair; 
   }
}
```

In your main:

```
thread -> create ( \&thread_func ) for 1..$workers; 
$work_q -> enqueue ( @correlatedPttns ); 
$work_q -> end; 
foreach my $thr ( threads -> list ) { 
    $thr -> join(); 
}
```

this will then start 10 workers, and each will work down your `work_q` one "pair" at a time. You can coalesce any results in a similar way with a results queue.

I will also point out - maintaining a list of threads yourself is redundant, because `threads->list` will do that for you.

Comment: HI Sobrique, you are right about how my program got killed. I noticed that with my original code, the memory usages gets bigger and bigger and finally program crashed. I have modified my code according to your suggestions and also come with another design:

Comment: There's still a lot of unnecessary overhead to spawning a new thread per 'pair'.

Answer (score 0):

here is **design 1** according to your suggestions:

```
my $workers = Sys::CPU::cpu_count();
my $work_q = Thread::Queue -> new();

threads->create (\&thread_func, \@pttnIndexMap, \@data, $cnt, $intervalOutput) for 1..$workers; 
$work_q -> enqueue ( @correlatedPttns ); 
$work_q -> end; 

foreach my $thr ( threads -> list() )
{    
    $thr -> join(); 
}
```

in the thread_func:

```
  sub thread_func
  {
    # omit here other stuffs
    while ( my $pair = $work_q -> dequeue() )
    {
         #get the element from @data (2D array) based on the $pair information and run processing
    }
  }
```

Here is **Design 2** based on limiting threads number of my original implementation:

```
my $number_of_cpus = Sys::CPU::cpu_count();
my $threadCnt = 0; 

foreach my $pair (@correlatedPttns)
{    
   # slice the data out
    my @tmp = ();
    for (my $x = 0; $x<$cnt; $x++)
    {
        push @tmp,[ @{ $data[$x] } [ 0, @$pair[0], @$pair[1] ] ]; # epochtime, Pi, Pj
    }

    threads->create (\&thread_func, $pair, \@pttnIndexMap, \@tmp,$cnt, $intervalOutput);
    $threadCnt++;

    if ($threadCnt >= $number_of_cpus)
    {
        $threadCnt = 0; 
        foreach my $thr ( threads -> list() )
        {
            $thr -> join(); 
        }
    }

}    

foreach my $thr ( threads -> list() )
{    
    $thr -> join();
}
```

Now both design work fine with the large dataset. However, I notice the big difference in terms of speed. **Design 1 works much slower than design 2**. In Design 1, I notice that it executes $workers threads, but each thread only uses <30% of CPU. On the other hand, design 2 executes 3 threads each time, and each thread uses 100% CPU.

The execution time for Design 1 is almost the same as sequential programming (without any multi-threading). Why? I notice that in Design 1, the @data (2d array) is used in the thread_func, each thread needs to access certain columns of the 2d array based on $pair information, will this slow down the multi-thread processing? In Design 2, I first slice those columns out before send it to thread_func, so that each thread is independent.

Thanks a lot!!